# MSG %USERNAME% /W

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm clipping data and waiting for a user to click "OK" on the messagebox before clipping a new line of data.

```
ECHO Site1| clip
MSG %USERNAME% /W  Site1 0315
ECHO Site2| clip
MSG %USERNAME% /W Site2 0315
```

I need it to wait until the user clicks "OK" in the popup before moving on.  This seems to wait 30 seconds.  Does anyone know how to make it actually wait until the user clicks?

## Update

@LotPings suggested I use PowerShell, which I was avoiding because a lot of my users are afraid of the term "script" but not "command line" or "batch".  Since each user has his or her own list of sites, I went with using a CSV for site and time and wrote the following PowerShell script:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$Data = Import-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\myFHA.csv
ForEach($a in $Data){
$a.site|clip
$wshell.popup($a.site+" at "+$a.time) |  Out-Null
}
```

I'd still really like to know how to make a `MSG` wait indefinitely in CMD, if it is possible.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What happens if you don't specify it to wait for a time?

Comment: Use `/TIME:seconds` with a very large number of seconds?

Comment: @Seth if I don't specify a time it seems to wait about 30 seconds

Comment: @DavidPostill if I change the /W to a /W /TIME:300 it seems to hold, but I was hoping there was a /TIME:-1 or something to make it permanent.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use `MSG`? Otherwise you could also give `SET /p` a try and just discard the input.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a vbscript or PowerShell for the popup. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410873/create-a-batch-file-that-displays-a-message-box-windows-10)

```
ECHO Site1| clip
>NUL powershell -NoP -C "(new-object -COM WScript.Shell).popup('Your message here.',0,'Site1 0315')"
ECHO Site2| clip
>NUL powershell -NoP -C "(new-object -COM WScript.Shell).popup('Your message here.',0,'Site2 0135')"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware I can do it through PowerShell, but I am going to distribute this to others and unfortunately PowerShell scares them.  I'm going to set each message to timeout after an hour for now.  If you know whether or not there's a function in CMD to keep the wait permanent (like a time:-1 [that doesn't work]) I'd appreciate it.

Comment: As long as you aren't scared, it shouldn't matter. It's used internal in the batch and the popup doesn't tell it's origin.

Comment: Nah, I guess I'll just have them use a CSV with their pertinent site info.  I wrote my own PowerShell script.  Thanks though.